# accessing global function with javascript using mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to validate the user before accessing the content. I have declared function globally and passing it inside the body. When I run it , I am getting error has: user doesn't exist . Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
function validate(user_id){ 
var user_id = db.query('select user_id from user WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id], 
function(error,rows) {
if (user_id != user_id) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
}); 
}

router.post('/addcustomerskills', function(req,res) {
if (validate(user_id == true)) {
  return true;
     // my code should execute
}else {
    response.success= false;
    response.mssg = "User Doesn't Exist";
    res.json(response);
}
```

Comment: try using this  db.query('select user_id from user WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id].toString(),functon(){...});

Comment: See what you're passing to `validate`: `if (validate(user_id == true))` ... a boolean. Then what is this condition supposed to do? `if (user_id != user_id)` ..?

Comment: if user_id is wrong , then it should return false

Comment: According to your question `validate` returns `false`. It always returns false, since you're passing a boolean to the function. Also you're redefining the passed `user_id` in the first line in the function body + checking if a variable isn't equal to itself doesn't make much sense in this case. Notice, that `"User doesn't exist"` is not an error, it is a value you return when your code can't find an user.

Comment: by default value will be false. If id not equal to the user entered id, then it should return false else true @Teemu

Comment: I am not arguing , i know  it's my typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(user_id, req, res){
    db.query('select user_id from user WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id], function(error,rows) {
        if (error || rows.length === 0) {
            var response = {}
            response.success= false;
            response.mssg = "User Doesn't Exist";
            res.json(response);
        } else {
            // my code should execute
            return true;
        }
    });
}

router.post('/addcustomerskills', function(req,res) {
    validate(req.body.user_id, req, res);
})
```

Comment: No, i am passing it has an paramater

Comment: you use express? Replace `validate(user_id)` to `validate(req.body.user_id)`, might be work.

Comment: jsut now i replaced the req.body technique , but still i got the same old error